# wxPython Update Progress Dialog from separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I'm attempting to run a progress dialog that isn't simply on a timer but updates based on the status of the files that are uploading to the server.  I don't care how the progress bar is visually represented, I just want it to be an accurate reflection of the process that it is tracking.  I've try to use `while` and `if` on the `thread.isAlive()` yet this won't give me an active bar while the process is running.  Here is the source for both the bar I'm using as well as the thread being called.

```
class ProgBar(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(
            self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Please wait."
            )
        self.Centre()
        max = 250

        dlg = wx.ProgressDialog(
            "Please wait.", 
            "Please wait while your request is processed.",
            maximum = max,
            parent=self,
            style = wx.PD_CAN_ABORT
            |wx.PD_APP_MODAL
            |wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE
            )

        keepGoing = True
        count = 0

        while keepGoing and count < max:
            count += 1
            wx.MilliSleep(50)

            if count >= max / 2:
                (keepGoing, skip) = dlg.Update(count)
            else:
                (keepGoing, skip) = dlg.Update(count)

        dlg.Destroy()
```

and the thread...

```
def UploadToServer(self, event):
    if PepTalkSource is None:
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,
        "You must attach a Pep Talk file!",
        "Missing Attachments!", wx.OK|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
    else:
        if os.path.isdir(
        r"\\server\address\goes\here"
        ):
            ThreadOne = FuncThread(CopyMove, ())
            ThreadOne.start()
            dlg = ProgBar()
            ThreadOne.join()
        else:
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,
            "The server could not be reached.  Please visit the Help Menu.",
            "Server Unavailable", wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
            result = dlg.ShowModal()
            dlg.Destroy()
```

I've even tried to ditch the class and insert the dialog straight into the function with no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just wrote about this sort of thing on my blog earlier this month:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/04/wxpython-how-to-update-a-progress-bar-from-a-thread/

What I think you need is the wx.Gauge widget. You can use Python to determine the size of the files you are uploading and use that information to set the gauge's range. Then you'll want to do the upload itself in a thread, but in chunks. So you'll read the file in chunks too, like 1024K and write it to the server in those same chunks. After each write, you update the progress bar.

Comment: So I assume that I can use an os.path.getsize() to handle the sizing of the files.  Question for you though, will I have to use a list like you do for range to iterate through the files as they upload and talk back to the guage that way?

Comment: Okay, so new problem.  I've been reading through the logging cookbook and I actually misspoke now that I think about what is actually executing in my script.  I'm not 'uploading' so much as copying.  All the info is going to a sharepoint shared documents folder that is mapped on the users drive.  Sorry for the confusion in that.

Comment: I would use os.stat to get the file size of each of the files and then total them up and use that for your gauge's range.